# IAR EW ORG directive in versions higher than 4.x

Tags: assembly, arm, iar

I'm porting a code made in IAR 4.41A to be build in IAR 7.40.

I've read the [Migration Guide](http://ftp.iar.se/WWWfiles/arm/webic/doc/EWARM_MigrationGuide.ENU.pdf) and I'm following its guides. It looks to me the bigger differences are in porting from version 4.x to 5.x.

The code I am working on have some org directives in a assembler file (`astartup.s79`). The migration guide says the ORG directive was removed in version 5, but says nothing about what code changes I must make to get the same behavior as before. I also did a Google search, but couldn't find anything useful about this subject (Query was, trying with some variations, `iar 5 ORG directive arm`).

The IAR Assembler gives me an `Error[40]: Bad instruction` at the lines where this directive is in. The [Assembler Reference Guide](http://ftp.iar.se/WWWfiles/arm/webic/doc/EWARM_AssemblerReference.ENU.pdf) have no references to the ORG directive, and I also couldn't find anything similar to it.

My question is: anyone knows how to solve this problem? What can I do to make this code build in newer IAR versions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, digging around I think I found the solution.

http://supp.iar.com/Support/?note=17934

According to this site, I have to place my code into segments, and then define the address of these segments in the linker file.